# Bounty asking for a new answer to a different question

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/18544/how-to-cut-threads-on-2-pvc-pipe) about threading a plastic pipe has an accepted answer saying "you don't, you buy the appropriate adapter".

Now someone has offered a bounty for an answer showing him a picture of said adapter.

Frankly, it's an easy 200 points to go look up an adapter picture, but, basically it's asking for shopping advice on an *old* question with an existing, accepted answer. It seems *wrong*...

I don't think we can "unbounty" the question, and I don't think that people can be prevented from answering it to get the bounty. What's the suggested course of action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bounties on an old question to raise attention and particularly to get new or updated answers is within the SO model. One of the [standard reasons to add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/09/23/bounty-reasons-and-post-notices/) is to "Improve Details".

Where we differ is whether this is looking for shopping advice. We often encourage photos for both questions, and when appropriate the answers. Since it's not looking for vendor referrals, product links, etc, but rather the name or photo of a type of product that they can then search for on their own, I feel this is within the norms of our site.

(Those opinions are mostly my own, and of course should the community differ with me, I'll happy work to enforce any policy/direction set by the community.)

Comment: OK. I answered the question. I guess there's no reason to turn down 200 points then.